# What is wrong with the following producer consumer code using the FutureTask class?

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

Yes, this is yet another question on producer/consumer in Java.

My variant is that I have N producers started by the `produceDataRows` method and M consumers started by the `consumeDataRows` method.
Both methods start their own instance of the `ThreadPoolExecutor` class, submit the respective number of producer/consumer tasks and then wait until their executors complete.

So, here is my code:

```
final BlockingQueue<Row> allRows = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Row>();
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
FutureTask<Object> producer = new FutureTask<Object>(new Callable<Object>() {
  @Override
  public Object call() throws Exception {
    produceDataRows(allRows);
    return null;
  }
});
FutureTask<Object> consumer = new FutureTask<Object>(new Callable<Object>() {
  @Override
  public Object call() throws Exception {
    consumeDataRows(allRows);
    return null;
  }
});
exec.execute(producer);
exec.execute(consumer);
producer.get();
consumer.get();
```

The problem is that `consumer.get()` returns, but `consumeDataRows` is never called. The `produceDataRows`, on the other hand is called.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

Following the reply by Gray, I have rewritten the code as follows:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
Callable<Object> producer = new Callable<Object>() {
  @Override
  public Object call() throws Exception {
    produceDataRows(allRows);
    return null;
  }
};
Callable<Object> consumer = new Callable<Object>() {
  @Override
  public Object call() throws Exception {
    consumeDataRows(allRows);
    return null;
  }
};
exec.submit(producer);
exec.submit(consumer);
exec.shutdown();
exec.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

The same effect - the code terminates, but `consumeDataRows` is never called. I have three different  ThreadPoolExecutor instances here - one in `produceDataRows`, one in `consumeDataRows` and the last one here.

Thanks.

**EDIT 2**

There is something wrong with my `produceDataRows` method, because if I comment it out, then execution visits the `call` method of both callables. Trying to figure it out now.

Comment: So there is a race condition right?  Could it be that the producer is not producing the rows _before_ the consumer goes to consume them?  Are you sure that `consumeDataRows` is actually called or are you saying that the rows that are produced are not consumed?

Comment: How are you running this code? inside a main method?

Comment: @Gray - The consumer method is never called. The `call` method of the respective callable is not called - the breakpoint is never visited.

Comment: @Ravi - The code is not inside the main method, but it is inside the main thread in a method directly invoked by the main.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you @mark.  You sure you aren't submitting the `producer` twice?  If you submit the `consumer` callable, `call()` will be called.  I'd add some `println` statements.  Maybe the debugger is confused.

Comment: @Gray - sorry to have taken your time. I think this is a problem with the IntelliJ debugger. If I place a breakpoint inside the producer and consumer callable, then it just does not stop on the consumer breakpoint. But, I know it is there, since it prints the debug messages I have added. If I only place a breakpoint on the consumer callable, then it does stop there. Again, sorry to have wasted your time and thanks.

Comment: I am changing the profile of the question to address the IntelliJ folks.

Comment: @mark it's sort of not fair to keep on changing the question.  I've provided an answer for your initial issue.  Maybe start another question around debugging issues if necessary?

Comment: @Gary - fair enough. I will start another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

I think you have a race condition here.  Since the producer and the consumer are both running *at the same time*, I bet the consumer goes to see what rows are in `allRows` and gets none because the producer has not done anything yet.

You will need to run the producer ahead of time or have the consumer use `allRows.poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` to wait for the results of the producer.  Maybe the producer could set a `volatile boolean producedAll = true` once it had produced all of the the rows and completed, and have the consumer looping with `.poll(...)` waiting for the `producedAll` to be true.

---

You have your classes a bit confused.  You should be calling `exec.submit(...)` on your `Callable` *not* instantiating and executing a `FutureTask`.  `submit(...)` then returns a `Future` which you can call `get()` on.

What you are doing now is instantiating your own `FutureTask` which is done internally by the `ExecutorService` -- never by the caller.  When you are then calling `get()` on your `FutureTask`, it is just returning immediately and not doing any joining or anything.  It works (unfortunately) because `FutureTask` is a `Runnable`.

Your code should be doing something like:

```
Future<Object> producer = exec.submit(new Callable<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
       produceDataRows(allRows);
       return null;
    }
});
Future<Object> consumer = exec.submit(new Callable<Object>() {
    ...
});
producer.get();
consumer.get();
```

Btw, typically I use `Callable<Void>` if I don't care about the return from a `Callable` since I just want the `Exception`.  I still return `null` but `Void` is useful when you want a no-value object.

Comment: The consumer method is just not called - I have a breakpoint and it is never visited.

Comment: Apparently, it is an IntelliJ issue.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are running this from inside a `main` method and the `thread` that runs main dies before other two threads can finish with their work.

I would suggest `joining` your thread to the other threads so that the main thread waits for other threads completion.

Comment: How can it be? The `awaitTermination` method gives it 10 days to complete.